# how to correctly write HTML markup inside PHP echo outputs

Tags: php, html

I am not able to write the HTML inside the PHP properly. The main problem is that I am not able to render the `<td>` with `class="btn"`.

```
    <tbody class="text-center">
    <?php
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $name=$row['name'];
           $email=$row['email'];
           $password=$row['password'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$name</td>";
            echo "<td>$email</td>";
            echo "<td>$password</td>";

            echo (<td><span class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</span></td>)";
            echo `<td>
            <span class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</span>
            </td>
        echo "</tr>`;
        }
```

Comment: See also [this infographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgkl8.png) re using `<?=` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways of doing this:

## 1) Escape

Use backslashes to escape the quotes within the PHP string, this is only needed when the quotes within are the same as the quotes encapsulating the PHP string:

```
echo "<td><span class=\"btn btn-outline-primary\">Edit</span></td>";
```

## 2) Alternative quotes

Use the "other" quote style within the HTML; such as if you use double-quotes `"` to encapsulate the PHP string, then use single quotes `'` within the HTML markup.

```
echo "<td><span class='btn btn-outline-primary'>Edit</span></td>";
```

## 3) "here document" syntax

PHP Print function also uses the "[here document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)" syntax to output
multiple lines with `$variable` interpolation.
**Note:** that the here document terminator must appear on a
line with just a semicolon no extra whitespace!

```
print <<<END
<td><span class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</span></td>
END;
```

My preferred/recommended option is to use **method 2**.

Please refer to [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the code right way or follow the standard.
You need backslash before quote sign inside echo

```
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$name</td>";
        echo "<td>$email</td>";
        echo "<td>$password</td>";

        echo "<td><span class=\"btn btn-outline-primary\">Edit</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"btn btn-outline-danger\">Delete</span></td>";        
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: thanks @martin . i add one more sentence. i'm sure a sample better dan long explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**The following way also working for your code**

When we use Quotes `"` inside a Quote we need to use the other Quote `'`

```
<?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr>
             <td>$row['name']</td>
             <td>$row['email']</td>
             <td>$row['password']</td>
             <td>
             <span class='btn btn-outline-primary'>Edit</span>
             </td>
             <td>
             <span class='btn btn-outline-danger'>Delete</span>
             </td>
             </tr>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if You will use *this* implementation everything will be fine :)
[foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [echo usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) and [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

```
<tbody class="text-center">
<?php foreach($result as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['password']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Ahhh, a variation I missed! Drat you! haha.

Comment: See also [this infographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgkl8.png) re using `<?=` .

Comment: According to [PHP FIG](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) (ie best practise), `<?PHP` and `?>` tags should be on their own lines. I had edited your answer to do this for you but these havn't been carried forward `:-/`